# How to call a Jenkinsfile or a Jenkins Job from another Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

On a *scripted pipeline* written in *Groovy*, I have 2 Jenkinsfiles namely - `Jenkinsfile1` and `Jenkinsfile2`.

Is it possible to call `Jenkinsfile2` from `Jenkinsfile1`.

Lets say following is my `Jenkinsfile1`

```
#!groovy

stage('My build') {
    node('my_build_node') {
        def some_output = True
        if (some_output) {
            // How to call Jenkinsfile2 here?
        }
    }
}
```

How do I call `Jenkinsfile2` above when output has a value which is not empty?

Or is it possible to **call another Jenkins job** which uses `Jenkinsfile2`?

Answer (score 4):

Your question wasn't quite clear to me. If you just want to load and evaluate some piece of Groovy code into yours, you can use `load()` (as @JoseAO previously stated). Apart from his example, if your file (`Jenkinsfile2.groovy`) has a `call()` method, you can use it directly, like this:

```
node('master') {
    pieceOfCode = load 'Jenkinsfile2.groovy'
    pieceOfCode()
    pieceOfCode.bla()
}
```

Now, if you want to trigger another job, you can use the `build()` step, even if you're not using a declarative pipeline. The thing is that the pipeline you're calling must be created in Jenkins, because `build()` takes as an parameter the job name, not the pipeline filename. Here's an example of how to call a job named `pipeline2`:

```
node('master') {
    build 'pipeline2'
}
```

Now, as for your question "How do I call Jenkinsfile2 above when output has a value which is not empty?", if I understood correctly, you're trying to run some shell command, and if it's empty, you'll load the Jenkinsfile/pipeline. Here's how to achieve that:

```
// Method #1
node('master') {
    try {
        sh 'my-command-goes-here'
        build 'pipeline2' // if you're trying to call another job
        
        // If you're trying to load and evaluate a piece of code
        pieceOfCode = load 'Jenkinsfile2.groovy'
        pieceOfCode()
        pieceOfCode.bla()       
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        print("${e}")
    }
}

// Method #2
node('master') {
    def commandResult = sh script: 'my-command-goes-here', returnStdout: true

    if (commandResult.length() != 0) {
        build 'pipeline2' // if you're trying to call another job
        
        // If you're trying to load and evaluate a piece of code
        pieceOfCode = load 'Jenkinsfile2.groovy'
        pieceOfCode()
        pieceOfCode.bla()       
    }
    else {
        print('Something went bad with the command.')
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

For example, your Jenkisfile2 it's my "pipeline2.groovy".

```
    def pipeline2 = load (env.PATH_PIPELINE2 + '/pipeline2.groovy')
    pipeline2.method()
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: This is how you can call other Jenkisfile2 inside a Jenkinsfile....